# CSS Animation [background-image] пробел между повторениями

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-animation

Есть простая анимация смены фонового изображения

```
body {
      animation: slideshow 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_1.jpg);
  }

  33% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_2.jpg);
  }

  70% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_3.jpg);
  }
}
```

Но беда в том что между показами анимаций появляется белый фон, я не силён  в этом - не подскажите что нужно сделать для решения?

Answer (score 0):

Поставь значения не 70% а 100% и тогда белый фон появляться не будет

```
body {
      animation: slideshow 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_1.jpg);
  }

  33% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_2.jpg);
  }

  100% {
      background-image: url(/img/bg_3.jpg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить `both`:

```
animation: slideshow 6s linear infinite both;
```